# Folder Browser Dialog in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm looking for a Folder Browser Dialog in asp.net like the winform's FolderBrowserDialog

```
DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
```

But there is no feature for this in ASP.net. By the way I'm not looking at Treeview list because the user has to select a folder from a drive or the network.

So is it possible to run winform in a web page? And if so, please provide an example?

Comment: Have you looked at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21895/Directory-Browsing-in-ASP-Net?

Comment: Yes I have checked but the problem is the root directory. root was defined as   TreeNode onjParent = new TreeNode("D:\\", "D:\\"); in the example. So when I change the new TreeNode("\\", "\\") can't get the folder which are in Network. So the winform is the best solution for the folder dialog but I cant use it at web page.

Comment: Do you want to upload a file? There are pretty good file upload controls  available for ASP.NET which lets you browse files and folders.

Comment: I dont want to upload a file. I'm looking for folder browser dialog. User can select the folder name.

Comment: @MuratFurkanSönmez Did you find any solution for this? I am also looking for this to take selected path as input. Trying since days, but no result till now. I would be glad if you could please share your knowledge